# Instantiating ImageButtons outside of Activity

Tags: android

Hi Im using several Image buttons that are displayed at the bottom of each activity, and I was wondering if there is any way to instantiate the objects outside of their respective activities Oncreate as they do the same thing in each activity but I do not want to be repeating code..

Any advice would be greatly appreciated thanks.
Marc

at the moment i am receiving a null pointer exception when trying to call the build() function.

**Here is my menu where tabs will display at the bottom**

```
    package koodoo.hcp.plus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import koodoo.hcp.utilities.Tabbuilder;

public class Hcp_Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

/**
 * Stores all the buttons within the HCP_Menu Activity
 */
ImageButton groupBtn;
ImageButton readingBtn;
ImageButton activityBtn;
ImageButton calendarBtn;
ImageButton ongoingBtn;

Context context = this;

View view = new View(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hcp__menu);

    Tabbuilder tb = new Tabbuilder();
    tb.build(view, context);

    /**
     * Create Activity Buttons
     */
    //group button
    groupBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonGroup);
    groupBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //reading button
    readingBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonReading);
    readingBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //activity button
    activityBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonActivity);
    activityBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //calendar button
    calendarBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCalender);
    calendarBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    //ongoing button
    ongoingBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonOngoing);
    ongoingBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    /**
     * create Tab buttons
     *//*

    //dash tab
    dashTab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dashButton);
    dashTab.setOnClickListener(this);

    //stats tab
    statsTab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.statsButton);
    statsTab.setOnClickListener(this);

    //invite tab
    inviteTab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.inviteButton);
    inviteTab.setOnClickListener(this);

    //settings tab
    settingsTab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
    settingsTab.setOnClickListener(this);

    //log tab
    logTab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.logButton);
    logTab.setOnClickListener(this);*/




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hcp__menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * onclick function for each button on the Activity.
 * @param v
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent i;

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageButtonGroup:  i = new Intent(this, Group.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonActivity:  i = new Intent(this, Activities.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonCalender:  i = new Intent(this, Calender.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonOngoing: i = new Intent(this, Ongoing.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonReading: i = new Intent(this, Reading.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

            default:
                break;

    }

}
}
```

**Tabbuilder class**

```
package koodoo.hcp.utilities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import koodoo.hcp.plus.Hcp_Menu;
import koodoo.hcp.plus.Invite;
import koodoo.hcp.plus.Log;
import koodoo.hcp.plus.R;
import koodoo.hcp.plus.Settings;
import koodoo.hcp.plus.Stats;

/**
 * Created by Marc Davies on 18/09/2013.
 */
public class Tabbuilder {

    ImageButton dashTab;
    ImageButton statsTab;
    ImageButton inviteTab;
    ImageButton settingsTab;
    ImageButton logTab;

    public void build(View v, final Context context) {

        /**
         * create Tab buttons
         */

        //dash tab
        dashTab = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.dashButton);
        dashTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Hcp_Menu.class);

            }
        });

        //stats tab
        statsTab = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.statsButton);
        statsTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Stats.class);

            }
        });

        //invite tab
        inviteTab = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.inviteButton);
        inviteTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Invite.class);

            }
        });

        //settings tab
        settingsTab = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        settingsTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Settings.class);

            }
        });

        //log tab
        logTab = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.logButton);
        logTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Log.class);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base activity and instantiate buttons in it. Now let other activities inherit the base activity. Dont forget to handle the layouts properly though

Comment: Is it possible to set Onclick functions within the base activity?

Comment: Yes, as long as you do the proper setContentView()

Answer (score 2):

you can make a utils class with static initiate Methods.

Those would take a context and an image and return an imageButton. You would still call that in the onCreate of the corresponding Activity, but you wouldnt have to copy paste your code anymore.

Comment: Equally good idea id up one you both but i dont have the rep yet ill try both methods but what im looking for is a method that will improve efficiency and speed of the app.

Comment: You have to init another button, if you want 2 second one. So there is no way i could think of to speed this up :)

Comment: How its meant to work is i have 5 image buttons that run along the bottom of each activity so like i said i dont want to repeat code over and over so could I instantiate each one in a single function?

Comment: if you use one button in all activity, you would keep a reference to the activity that craeted it, so this wont be disposed even if not actually displaying the activity. so you would habe to create button on appContext.

Comment: I seem to be receiving a null pointer exception when i call the function should i be passing the function the view in which it is creating the buttons?

Comment: where does the nullpointer come from? it needs a context, a context can be the activity or just a regular context, and the Image.

Comment: it does come when i call the tabBuilder and and it tries to create the ImageButton ill post up my code

Comment: Ive uploaded my code im sending it a context aswell as a view.

Comment: Have you found your nullpointer yet? Othwerwise Highlight the Line where it occurs